# How to limit the returned fields and exclude _id in mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, scope, mongoid, projection

I want to get specific document attributes and exclude the `_id`s. This is my controller action:

```
def index
  @humans = Human.only([:name, :dob])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @humans.to_json(:except => :_id) }
  end
end
```

It works fine but I see this as a workaround rather than as the proper way to do what I want.

Ideally I would like to say something like `@humans = Human.only([:name, :dob]).without(:_id)` but this doesn't work as you can't combine `only` with `without` in mongoid. However, mongo allows you to use projections to exclude just the `_id` from a specific set of included attributes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to https://github.com/nesquena/rabl
This helps you render lighter json responses. You can either create some keys and build there values with whatever you want without pollute your controller.

Comment: I am failing to see how this is relevant to my problem. My json rendering is okay, I only want to limit the fields the query at the top returns.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misunderstand your question.

Answer (score 0):

How about `Human.pluck(:name, :dob)`? It may not be exactly what you need though.